# Python share directory over HTTP

Tags: python

I got a script to share directory over web url by python. The script running the web server under port 8000. The port definition not available on the script. Here I have listed the script.

```
import os
import posixpath
import urllib
import BaseHTTPServer
from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
import os

dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
docroot = os.path.join(dir, 'webdir')

# modify this to add additional routes
ROUTES = (
    # [url_prefix ,  directory_path]
    ['/docroot', docroot+'css'],
    ['', docroot]  # empty string for the 'default' match
) 

class RequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

    def translate_path(self, path):
        """translate path given routes"""

        # set default root to cwd
        root = os.getcwd()

        # look up routes and set root directory accordingly
        for pattern, rootdir in ROUTES:
            if path.startswith(pattern):
                # found match!
                path = path[len(pattern):]  # consume path up to pattern len
                root = rootdir
                break

        # normalize path and prepend root directory
        path = path.split('?',1)[0]
        path = path.split('#',1)[0]
        path = posixpath.normpath(urllib.unquote(path))
        words = path.split('/')
        words = filter(None, words)

        path = root
        for word in words:
            drive, word = os.path.splitdrive(word)
            head, word = os.path.split(word)
            if word in (os.curdir, os.pardir):
                continue
            path = os.path.join(path, word)

        return path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BaseHTTPServer.test(RequestHandler, BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer)
```

Can any one help me to edit the cord to define custom port. Some thing like "80".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     server_class=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
     server_address = ('', 80)
     httpd = server_class(server_address, RequestHandler)         
     httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: This answer well suit to my problem. thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 5):

Python comes [with batteries included](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html). Use

```
python -m http.server 8000
```

where `8000` is the port.

Comment: I'm new to python. where i can include this line on above script?

Comment: This isn't used inside a script, it's used on the command line within the directory that you want to host.  Use `cd` to switch to your directory and then run that command.

Answer (score 0):

The one of the fastest ways will be

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

Useful links:

- https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html
- http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/

If you can't access created website, check your user permissions.